# Use of OnPaint() function in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to learn MFC doc-view application. I've started with creating a simple image viewer application. For this I've derived my view class from CScrollView class and overridden the draw() function.

I wanted to know when to use OnPaint() function and how it is related with draw() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need both an `OnPaint` and `OnDraw` function in the same view. According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssdhfz2t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> When a view becomes invalid, Windows sends it a WM_PAINT message. The view's OnPaint handler function responds to the message by creating a device-context object of class CPaintDC and calls your view's OnDraw member function. You do not normally have to write an overriding OnPaint handler function.

By splitting the drawing code into its own function, the framework allows you to reuse it for both painting the screen and printing.

Comment: Overriding `OnPaint` is almost always wrong for views - and when it's right it usually involves advanced stuff. For example, you might want to override both when you trying to do double or triple buffering and you need to juggle device contexts. As the documentation states, keep the drawing inside `OnDraw`.

Comment: In my test application I've overridden the Draw() function, which is loading the image and drawing it. Now I want to add zoom-in/zoom-out capability to the application. For this I've added toolbar button. I am not getting how to proceed with this. What I have to do in toolbar handler. Do I need to change the CImage object of the view class and called update window. Will it be correct or there is some better way for the same.

Comment: @dearvivekkumar you should ask additional questions in a *new* question - not comments. But generally, have your toolbar button set a "zoom level" member variable in the view, and then have the `OnDraw` draw things accordingly.